# apache bench gnuplot output - what are the column definitions?

Tags: performance-testing, apachebench

I am using ApacheBench to get some basic timing information.  Meeting my needs very well.  I noticed that "-g file" creates a tab delim'ed file with each call as a row.  I am unable to determine the definition of the columns however.  Here is my best guess:

**starttime**: self-explanatory, the time that this call started

**seconds**: based on data, I think this may be "starttime" in a different format

**ctime**: ?, has a 0 value for each row for me, so no idea

**dtime**, **ttime**, **wait**: either dtime or ttime or wait appear to be the "time that this call took in ms"

The [AB documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) doesn't seem to cover the output format.  Anyone know what these columns mean, or where I can find some documentation?

Comment: Would love to find some documentation on Apache Bench! The man page explains the command line args, but does not explains the output, leaving us to guess.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is what I have deduced:

- ctime: Connection Time
- dtime: Processing Time
- ttime: Total Time
- wait: Waiting Time

How I deduced this:

```
$ ab -v 2 -n 1 -c 1 -g output.txt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929104/apache-bench-gnuplot-output-wha
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking stackoverflow.com (be patient)...INFO: POST header ==
---
GET /questions/5929104/apache-bench-gnuplot-output-what-are-the-column-definitions HTTP/1.0
Host: stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: ApacheBench/2.3
Accept: */*


---
LOG: header received:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Thu, 26 May 2011 19:24:52 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 26 May 2011 19:23:52 GMT
Vary: *
Date: Thu, 26 May 2011 19:23:51 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 29118

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<title>performance testing - apache bench gnuplot output - what are the column definitions? - Stack Overflow
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></scrip
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=005820c36f6e"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=d75e6659067e">


    <link rel="canonical" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929104/apache-bench-gnuplot-output-what-
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed for question 'apache bench gnuplot output
..done


Server Software:
Server Hostname:        stackoverflow.com
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /questions/5929104/apache-bench-gnuplot-output-what-are-the-column-definitions
Document Length:        29118 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   0.330 seconds
Complete requests:      1
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      29386 bytes
HTML transferred:       29118 bytes
Requests per second:    3.03 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       329.777 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       329.777 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          87.02 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       79   79   0.0     79      79
Processing:   251  251   0.0    251     251
Waiting:       91   91   0.0     91      91
Total:        330  330   0.0    330     330
```

Compare to:

```
$ cat output.txt
starttime       seconds ctime   dtime   ttime   wait
Thu May 26 12:24:02 2011        1306437842      79      251     330     91
```

Comment: Is waiting time == processing time? That is waiting time?

Comment: +1 for approach to prove it! Just to add for other readers, see as well on laktak's answer. Waiting time (`wait`) is time waiting for first byte to arrive from server. `ctime` is time wait for connection to be completely established. `dtime` is the processing time. `ttime` is total time included `ctime` and `dtime`.

Answer (score 11):

There's a good explanation [here](https://blog.tom-fitzhenry.me.uk/2014/08/apache-bench-timings-visualised.html) (including `wait` that's missing from the accepted answer):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I came to the same results as saltycrane, but want to make some additions (and want to sum things up):

- starttime: self-explanatory, the time that this call started (as stated in question)
- seconds: starttime as unix timestamp (`date -d @1306437842` returns starttime output)
- ctime: Connection Time
- dtime: Processing Time
- ttime: Total Time (ttime = ctime + dtime)
- wait: Waiting Time